# What is the Big-O of this piece of code?

Tags: c, time-complexity, big-o

Recently I had an exam in which was this question: what is the time-complexity of g?

```
int f(int *arr, int n, int m)
{
    if(n == 0)
    {
        if(m == 0)
            return 3;

        return arr[m] + f(arr, n, m - 1);
    }

    return f(arr, n - 1, m);
}

int g(int *arr, int n)
{
    return f(arr, n, n);
}
```

Now, me and most of my friends answered O(n), as there are clearly 2*n calls for f and nothing else, but the answer of the professor was O(n^2).
Can someone explain to me who is right? if it's him, can you please explain why?

Comment: It's O(n) as written, and your analysis is right. Are you sure you didn't mis-transcribe the problem, and the inner call is to `f(arr, m, m-1)`? As written, it doesn't make much sense to reference `n` in the inner call `f(arr, n, m-1)` since at that point `n` is always 0.

Comment: I checked it very carefully and it is n and not m. I suspect that the professor actually mistaken it to m and said O(n^2) because of that.

Comment: `O(n*m)` however the function call is `n==m` so its `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

In post, I realize that I was solving the wrong problem. I was solving for when the inner function call is `f(arr, m, m - 1)`. In that case, the time complexity is indeed O(n²). The way the question was posted, the time complexity is O(n). However, I will leave this post as this is most likely the way the professor mistook it as well. Thus, the following answer is written the way the exam question was likely intended for reference.

Consider the steps that are taken:

1. Call `f()` n times recursively, meaning that `n == 0` n calls down the stack.
2. Now, in this lowest function call, we can enter the if statement.
3. We call `f()` again, reducing m, but MAINTAINING the original n value by calling with m as the second argument as well.
4. In this 'new'  recursive stack, we must first call `f()` n (or m) times again before we can reduce m by 1 once more.
5. Once `m == 0`, we can return.

Look at this graph, where every 'unit' represents one call to `f()`. When `n == 0`, we call with the third argument again and reduce m by 1, so we drop down a level.
[image: A graph of n and m values]

Since the area of the rectangle in this graph is `n * m` and `m == n`, that means that `f()` is called `n²` times and the code has O(n²) time complexity.

Comment: "We call f() again, reducing m, but MAINTAINING the original n value" - how is that? At the time of that call n is always 0.

Comment: Sorry, editing the question now. Seems I was solving for the wrong problem. It was probably the way it was intended though. The edit will thus focus on that.